# Using remote attribute in .net core razor pages. Data get lost on return to page

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, jsonresult

Referring to
[My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870186/using-remote-attribute-in-net-core-razor-pages-the-parameter-does-not-get-valu)
The problem is this that the data get lost once returned from the Action Method of the controller. **The values in the textbox as well as in the dropdownlist becomes empty**. However, the error message is displayed successfully. "Keyword already exists".

Comment: The `Keyword already exists` message shows the remote check works , that should be any other issue on your page to make the textbox empty .

Comment: the remote attribute returns JSON with 0. I think this cause the dropdownlist to get empty

Comment: That is ajax request , won't modify your markup unless you changed that .